# Modifying a list based on the length of its shortest string

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

I have a list of two series that start out the same length. After executing the following code, the second series has one fewer elements than the first. Is there a general way of removing the final element of only the series containing n+1 elements, so that all the series in my list have n elements? What about if I have a combination of series in my list containing n, n+1 and n+2 elements? Below is a minimal reproducible example.

```
#test
library('urca')
tseries <- list("t1" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1), "t2" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,9));

# apply stationarity test to the list of series
adf <- lapply(tseries, function(x) tseries::adf.test(x)$p.value)
adf

# index only series that need differencing
not_stationary <- tseries[which(adf > 0.05)]
stationary <- tseries[which(adf < 0.05)]
not_stationary <- lapply(not_stationary, diff);

# verify
adf <- lapply(not_stationary, function(x) tseries::adf.test(x)$p.value)
adf
now_stationary <- not_stationary

#combine stationary and now_stationary
tseries_diff <- c(stationary, now_stationary)
tseries_diff
#$t1
#[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1

#$t2
#[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1
```

So to summarise, I would ike to remove the final element, 1, from t1, but using code that can be applied to a list of series of lengths n and n+1 (and n+2 would be useful).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the minimum length and simply get the series up to that point, i.e.

```
new_series_list <- lapply(tseries_diff, function(i)i[seq(min(lengths(tseries_diff)))])
```

so the lengths are now the same

```
lengths(new_series_list)
#t1 t2 
#14 14
```

This will work in any size series. It will trim the long series to much the short one.

Answer (score 1):

Edited for list instead of vector -
**If you are dealing with list, you are wanting to make all of the series the length of the shortest:**

(I modify the example to avoid using a library)

```
#test
mylist <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
mylongerlist <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
length(mylist)
# [1] 5
length(mylongerlist)
# [1] 7

#combine 
tseries_diff <- list("t1" = mylist, "t2" = mylongerlist)
tseries_diff
# $t1
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
# 
# $t2
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

# on the fly approach to truncate
lapply(tseries_diff, function(x) { length(x) <- min(lengths(tseries_diff)); x })
# $t1
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
# 
# $t2
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

And a function

```
# As a reusable function for clear code
reduceToShortestLength <- function(toCut) {
  # takes a list and cuts the tail off of any series longer than the shortest
  lapply(toCut, function(x) { length(x) <- min(lengths(tseries_diff)); x })
  }
reduceToShortestLength(tseries_diff)
# $t1
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
# 
# $t2
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Original below (in case anyone thinks vector like I did at first) 
I think you are asking how to truncate a vector to the shortest length. The `head` function does this well in base R.

the on the fly approach:

```
> mylist <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
> mylongerlist <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
> length(mylist)
[1] 5
> length(mylongerlist)
[1] 7
> x <- head(mylongerlist, length(mylist))
> length(x)
[1] 5
```

A function can be written like so:

```
> reduceToShorterLength<- function(toshorten, template) { head(toshorten, length(template))}
> x <- reduceToShorterLength(mylongerlist, mylist)
> length(x)
[1] 5
```

Comment: Those aren't lists. They are vectors

Comment: Good call @Sotos - I misread the question (even though it says list).

Comment: yes because they are talking about a list with series (i.e. vectors). However, you are not treating them as list elements but rather as individual vectors. Also, how would they know which is the longer element in the list?